# Thymeleaf dropdown options dissappear after adding second dropdown in loop

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-applications, thymeleaf, bootstrap-5

this is my first question here so please be kind :D

I am in the middle of a UNI project which is a businesses scheduler.
I want to be able to add many task groups to my project, so I decided to do it with dropdown in a loop. Every time someone clicks on button new dropdown appears (not sure if it's best solution, but I'am still learning Spring and Thymeleaf). The problem is that when I have only one dropdown everything is fine.

[image]

But after I click on plus button the options from dropdown disappears.

[image]

I tried to find the answer on the internet but I can't find anything similar.

Here is my form code:

```html
  <form action="#" method="post" th:action="@{/projects}" th:object="${project}">
                <p class="C(red)" th:if="${#fields.hasAnyErrors()}" th:errors="*{all}"></p>
                <br/>
                <div><h2>New project</h2></div>
                <label>Description
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{description}" th:errorclass="'Bdc(red)'"/>
                </label>
                <fieldset th:each="projectGroup, projectGroupStat : *{selectedGroups}">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <select class="dropdown" th:field="*{selectedGroups[__${projectGroupStat.index}__]}"
                                th:id="${projectGroupStat.index}">
                            <option th:each="group: ${groups}" th:value="${group.id}"><a class="dropdown-item"
                                                                                         th:text="${group.description}"/>
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" name="addGroup">+</button> 
                </div>
                <br/>
                <p>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning">Clear</button>
                </p>
            </form>
```

Here is a part of my controller code:

```java
    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    String showProjects(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("project", new ProjectWriteModel());
        model.addAttribute("groups", getGroups());
        return "projects";
    }
    
    
    @PostMapping(params = "addGroup")
    String addProjectGroup(@ModelAttribute("project") ProjectWriteModel current){
        current.getSelectedGroups().add(new String());
        return "projects";
    }
    
    private List<GroupReadModel> getGroups() {
        return taskGroupService.readAll();
    }
```

Am I missing something here? I will be grateful for any help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I could figure out from the limited code that you have provided.

In the `addProjectGroup` you need to set the `groups` in the `Model`. Like:

```
model.addAttribute("groups", getGroups());
```

the same way that you did in the method `showProjects`. So this way it will be available to your HTML.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much! I thought this was a much more complex issue and the solution is so simple! Thank you, you are awesome! :D